# How to install PCManFM 1.0

Tags: lubuntu, pcmanfm

I use Lubuntu 12.04. The new PCManFM 1.0 version is not yet in the repos; how to get it?

Comment: Have you looked at the latest Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCMan_File_Manager or the latest builds on |Launchpad https://launchpad.net/~lubuntu-dev/+archive/lubuntu-daily/+build/3745770

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This answer is entirely taken from [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=175&t=110870)**.

1) Download both PCManFM-1.0 and libfm-1.0 to a working directory. Download links:

PCManFM: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcmanfm ... z/download

libfm: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcmanfm ... z/download

2) Working in a terminal emulator (e.g., LXTerminal), unzip libfm-1.0 in the working directory:

```
$ tar -xvzf libfm-1.0.tar.gz
```

3) Change to the new 'libfm-1.0' directory and issue the following command:

```
$ ./configure --sysconfdir=/etc
```

Some requirements may not be satisfied. ('intltool,' 'libgtk2.0-dev,' or 'libmenu-cache1-dev' and other dependencies to install in addition to those three packages, but just let synaptic take care of all that)

4) Upon successful completion of 3), issue the following command in the 'libfm-1.0' directory:

```
$ make
```

5) Optionally, you can run the following command to make sure everything compiled properly:

```
$ make check
```

6) Install 'libfm-1.0' by issuing the following command:

```
$ sudo make install
```

7) Working in a terminal emulator (e.g., LXTerminal) in the working directory, unzip pcmanfm-1.0.tar.gz:

```
$ tar -xvzf pcmanfm-1.0.tar.gz
```

8) Change to the new 'pcmanfm-1.0' directory

9) Issue the following commands in succesion, waiting for each to complete before the next:

```
$ ./configure --sysconfdir=/etc
$ make
$ make check
$ sudo make install
```

10) Kill the current running version of PCManFM by issuing the following command from LXTerminal:

```
$ killall pcmanfm
```

11) When trying to start PCManFM from the command line (e.g., `$ pcmanfm --desktop`), it may indicate that a library (libfm-gtk.so.3) was missing. The library actually may be on the system (in /usr/local/lib/), but not in the place PCManFM is looking (/usr/lib/), so a link is to be created. Two links in fact, to two different libraries (both libfm-gtk.so.3 and libfm.so.3). These are the commands to be used:

```
$ cd /usr/lib
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libfm-gtk.so.3.0.1 libfm-gtk.so.3
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libfm.so.3 libfm.so.3
```

12) Issue the following command to start PCManFM (or restart computer):

```
$ pcmanfm --desktop
```