# How can I see what version of pcmanfm I'm running?

Tags: versions, pcmanfm

I have a problem with pcmanfm (not accessible etc). I think this is related to the fact that [I had installed a 1.0 version](https://askubuntu.com/a/180988/47206), then purged and reinstalled but now I cannot tell what version I am using, while the initial problem is not yet solved..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command `apt-cache policy pcmanfm` in a terminal to see it. Alternatively you can also use the PcManFM GUI to see it. Go to *Menu → Help → About* to see the version.

As yet another method (as izx said in a comment), you can use `dpkg -l pcmanfm` to see the version number of it.

Comment: yes. or in synaptic. thnx

Comment: or use `dpkg -l pcmanfm`