# Install PCmanFM v1.1.2.2

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, filemanager, pcmanfm

I want to install the newest version of PCmanFM on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine. I have download the the newest version from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcmanfm/). Now how do i actually install it and make it so that it is the system wide default?
There is another [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180986/how-to-install-pcmanfm-1-0) maybe that can be updated for Ubuntu 13.04 and PCmanFm 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to download the source code for [pcmanfm v1.1.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcmanfm) and [libfm v1.1.2](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfm) **(For Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander)** from Launchpad.
Compile, create the deb packages and install them in **Ubuntu 13.04**.

#### NOTE: I would recommend you to test this in a Virtual Machine first, to see if everything is ok.

---

**1)** Make sure you have enable the **"Source code repository"**

- Open the Ubuntu Software Center
- In the Menu Bar choose **Edit -> Software Sources**. Click to enable **"Source code repository"**.
  Just in case I use the **"Main Server"** to Download.

[image]

And make sure you have also the **universe** repository enable.

Open a Terminal and type:

- `sudo apt-get update`

**2)** In the Terminal window type the following to install the necessary packages.

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential wget pcmanfm`

**3)** Install build dependencies.

- `sudo apt-get build-dep pcmanfm libfm`

**4)** Create folders to download the source code to compile & install libfm.

- `mkdir ~/Downloads/src`
- `cd ~/Downloads/src/ && mkdir pcmanfm libfm && cd libfm`

```bsh
cat > source-list <<EOF
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libfm_1.1.2-0ubuntu1.dsc
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libfm_1.1.2-0ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libfm_1.1.2.orig.tar.gz
EOF
```

- `wget -i source-list && dpkg-source -x libfm_1.1.2-0ubuntu1.dsc && cd libfm-1.1.2`
- `fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage && cd .. && sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

**5)** Download the source code to compile & install pcmanfm.

- `cd ../pcmanfm/`

```bsh
cat > source-list <<EOF
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/pcmanfm_1.1.2-0ubuntu1.dsc
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/pcmanfm_1.1.2-0ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/pcmanfm_1.1.2.orig.tar.gz
EOF
```

- `wget -i source-list && dpkg-source -x pcmanfm_1.1.2-0ubuntu1.dsc && cd pcmanfm-1.1.2`
- `fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage && cd .. && sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

**6)** Make PcManFM default File & Desktop Manager.

- `xdg-mime default pcmanfm.desktop inode/directory`
- `sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop.bak`
- `sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/pcmanfm-autostart.desktop`

The content of the **pcmanfm-autostart.desktop** file is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=File Manager PCManFM
Exec=pcmanfm --desktop
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
NoDisplay=true
```

- Save the changes in nano with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

**7)** Replace Nautilus icon for PCManFM in Unity Launcher.

- `favorites=$(gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites | sed 's/nautilus.desktop/pcmanfm.desktop/')`
- `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "$favorites"`

**8)** Restart Your Machine.

**9)** Finally open the PCManFM desktop preferences for customization (background,font etc).

- `pcmanfm --desktop-pref`

[image]

---

**RESULT:**

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: for step 2) I get 'E: Unable to locate package pcmanfm'

Comment: Okay I trying this new version now.

Comment: it works. pcmanfm but my desktop background is black and there are no icon except one for 'files'

Comment: the black background, you have to change it with the desktop preferences step 9.. about the icons.. step 7 read your settings with gseetings and change only the nautilus.desktop with pcmanfm.desktop and store in the variable $favorites, the set again in gseetings with all the icons you had it but the only diference is change the nautilus for pcmanfm.

Comment: for some reason if i go to settings and then go to background and change the wallpaper. it does not change

Comment: In wallpaper mode.. do you have the "stretch to fill the entire sreen"?